# #1060 - Duplicate column name 'ID' Why?

Tags: mysql, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicles` (

`UID` int(4) NOT NULL,

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,

`Kofferraum` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0|0|0|0|',

`Typ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Tuning` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

`Spawnpos_X` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Spawnpos_Y` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Spawnpos_Z` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Spawnrot_X` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Spawnrot_Y` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Spawnrot_Z` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Farbe` varchar(50) NOT NULL,

`Paintjob` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',

`Benzin` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '100',

`Slot` float NOT NULL,

`Special` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`Lights` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '|255|255|255|',

`Distance` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`STuning` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0|0|0|0|0|0|',

`AuktionsID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`GangVehicle` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`rc` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`spezcolor` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '|0|0|0|0|0|0|',

`Sportmotor` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`Bremse` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

`Antrieb` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

`plate` text NOT NULL,
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: So what's the part you left out? (the `[...]` part)

Comment: @Titanium you should not add futher information as an answer. Use the edit function at your question

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using 'id' twice.  Either remove the duplicate or change the name of this to something else:
ID int(11) NOT NULL

Answer (score 0):

You have the column id twice. Once at the beginning an one at the end.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vehicles` (

`UID` int(4) NOT NULL,

`id` int(11) NOT NULL,

...
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
...
```

remove one of them

Comment: Ah, My mistake Sorry